# Pluggable conventions in EF 5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Was Pluggable conventions removed from the EF 5 release, i saw it in the pre releases?  Looking for a way to force ef code use datetime2 by convention, so don't need to explicit map each column of every entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up create a derived class of EntityTypeConfiguration.

```
public class CustomEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    public TEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime2");
    }
}
```

Then each of the entity configurations just inherit from this instead of EntityTypeConfiguration.

Answer (score 2):

Came across a similar issue. I have a generic repository that has a BaseEntity similar to yours.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; } 
}
```

and then each entity is derived from the base.

```
public class MyEntity: BaseEntity
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I ended up setting the Created and Updated properties of the BaseEntity using a columm attribute like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; } 
}
```

I looked at your solution at (http://dreadjr.blogspot.com/2012/09/entity-framework-5-code-first-datetime2.html) and it looks fine too, but it requires to have a specific configuration class for each entity. Anyways, I thought I'll share this with you.